# fatal error: 'sodium/version.h' file not found white setting up libsodium-go

Tags: go, libsodium

I was working with the Github API in order create a script to transfer secrets from Gitlab.

While doing so I have been trying to setup the libsodium-go package to encrypt the secrets.
Here is the link for reference https://github.com/GoKillers/libsodium-go

I have followed the steps mentioned on the page.

```
Pre-setup:

Please install Libsodium here https://download.libsodium.org/doc/installation/index.html
sudo ldconfig
sudo apt-get install pkg-config

Install libsodium-go:

go get -d github.com/GoKillers/libsodium-go
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/GoKillers/libsodium-go
./build.sh
```

But for the pre setup have used `brew install libsodium`

When I run the `./build.sh`

I get the following error

```
In file included from cryptohash/crypto_hash.go:5:
/usr/local/include/sodium.h:5:10: fatal error: 'sodium/version.h' file not found
#include "sodium/version.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Not sure how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: libsodium is installing using ./configure, make and make install, however the golang package is not downloading, package downloads with a gitclone, and build.sh runs with warnings. it does not however produce a binary.

Comment: I did go ahead and try installing libsodium using brew. From the /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.18_1/include/ was able to copy the sodium folder to /usr/local/include. This seems to be a quick fix but still don't think its the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue, when I ran `brew install libsodium`, a warning was displayed stating that libsodium has been installed, it's just not linked.
To link run `brew link libsodium`. If conflicting files are found, running `brew link --overwrite libsodium` resolved the problem.